# split a string and save sub strings in list in dart

Tags: string, flutter, dart, split

I have a long String that contains comma-separated values. How can I split that string and save those substrings into List in dart/Flutter?
[image]

Please help me to do this

```
String myname = dd.data.toString();
```

Comment: It is not entirely clear! Can you describe the expected result?

Comment: I need cooma separed values from the above string.....example-> brand:sfdfgdf

Comment: So, I believe answer of @Tipu answers your question!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [split](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/split.html) for this.

```
String s = "a,b,c,d,e";

List<String> list = s.split(",");
```